# Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle ENUM

Tags: java, enums

I have enum and used it to combo box. However some of them seems with'-' and some of them seems without'-'. And strings with '-' gave Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle error.

```
public enum IslemTipi {

        ILK_KRLM,
        KOK_SRTFKA_VE_ANHTR_CFI_URTMI,
        ISLM_KAYDI_SORGLMA,
        YTKISZ_VERI_TBNI_MDHLE_TRMSI;
        private final String name;

        private IslemTipi() {
            this.name = null;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return ResourceBundleUtil.getLabelFromRb("IslemTipi." + name());
        }
 }
        public IslemTipi[] getIslemTipiValues() {
        return IslemTipi.values();
    }
```

Comment: Good lord, those enum items have built-in encryption :-)

Comment: Does `ResourceBundleUtil.getLabelFromRb("IslemTipi.ILK_KRLM")` work, or does it throw an Exception? If so then your problem lies there.

Comment: Another point, having `private final String name` is a little confusing, since it is similar to but not the same as `Enum.name()` - do you really need this? Or at least can you rename it?

Comment: @vikingsteve yes,"IslemTipi.ILK_KRLM" thows an exception and also "YTKISZ_VERI_TBNI_MDHLE_TRMSI" thows an exception.

Comment: Well then your problem is in the `getLabelFromRb()` method, not the enum - can you post some code from `ResourceBundleUtil` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve I solved the problem thanks a lot.I forgat these "ILK_KRLM" and "YTKISZ_VERI_TBNI_MDHLE_TRMSI"  to add the i18n file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely lies in your `ResourceBundleUtil` code - try to run the code below and resolve the source of the Exception.

`ResourceBundleUtil.getLabelFromRb("IslemTipi.ILK_KRLM");`

Also, a style tip is to rename `private final String name;` (or remove it if you don't need it) since it is confusing when seen next to `Enum.name()`.